# Gtkmm : How to update UI from another thread? continuously

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals, gtkmm

Thread A:  a UI thread where the Gtkmm's message loop runs.

Thread B:  receives data over network and logs it to a file.

Now I want that same data that's dumped into a file in thread B, also to be displayed in a Gtk::TextView on the UI at the same time. What's the nicest way to do that?

Glib::Dispatcher doesn't take data along. So it's only good for notifying about work-done's.

libSigCX just makes me sad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try using `Glib::Dispatcher` along with a `Glib::Threads::Mutex` (or equivalent) protected `std::queue<std::string>` data structure.  Use the dispatcher to notify the UI thread of each work item after you've put it on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should pass a UI structure pointer as parameter to the Thread B. The structure has already all the signals assigned that way you can use the TextView.